# Merging enums with methods

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I have found the practice of merging enums with namespaces very useful. example:

```
enum Status : {
    OK = 1,
    NOT_OK = 2,
}

namespace Status {

    function Color(status : Status) {

        if(status == Status.OK)
            return 'green';
        else
            return 'red';

    }

}
```

But I discovered that tslint doesn't like them...
What other methods can I use instead in order to get the same behavior?
I thought about replaccing the namespace in a class with static methods, but it has two disadvantages:

1) The class has to get a different name (for example 'StatusUtil') - ok, I can live with that...

2) The 'StatusUtil' class (unlike namespace) cannot be called directly from an HTML file when using Angular - which means that I have to write extra methods in each component, something like this:

```
getColor(status : Status) {
    return StatusUtil(status);
}
```

Another option that I thought about was using an Angular dependency injection istead of static method.
What do you think will be the best practice?

Comment: Tslint has a blanket rule against namespaces. You should avoid using namespaces instead of modules, but merging is still a valid use for them.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30994#issuecomment-492024848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good case to suppress the tslint warning. Tslint is there to point out possible issues with your code, but you can suppress these in code using a comment.

The rule is there to prevent usage of namespaces for code organisation, but Typescript still has scenarios around merging that can only be achieved using namespaces.

Directly from weswigham (a ts team member) in a [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30994#issuecomment-492024848):

> > Is namespace merging with class, function and enum a 'good' use of namespaces?
>
> Sometimes - since we can't recognize ad-hoc attachments of certain kinds of static properties, it might be warranted - in many cases an ad-hoc property on a function or a class static will suffice (unless you need it to contain types), though. Although it's just as valid to question if you really needed the merge to begin with - if, for example, you want to associate a component and its argument type, isn't exporting both of them from the same module sufficient? Why also wrap them in a namespace? There's no point there.
>
> It comes down to this:
>
> If you're considering using namespaces for code organization: *Don't*. Modules have subsumed that role.
> If you need functionality that only namespaces can provide: *Do*, but check that it's not equally expressive to express the concept without a namespace (eg, with a class static or function property, or reexported module). It is also bad style to mix namespaces and modules in the same project - it just feels off, since one of the major features of namespaces in the traditional sense is cross-file scope merging, which doesn't occur across modules (since, as I said, the module itself is actually a namespace).

Also in that thread, namespaces are not going to be removed from the language so using them for specific scenarios is ok.